# MapControl initialization animation

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible to get on load Map without animation like "jumping" from Africa to specified coordinates?

Currently I use this code to set Map center coordinates:

```
MyMap.SetView(new GeoCoordinate(Latitude, Longitude), 17);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mikhail, a quick Google search could provide you this answer.

Anyhow here is a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.mapanimationkind%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for what you are looking for.